# Create a rewrite rule taking a variable input and redirecting to a file with query string

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

How do I write a rewrite rule so that it takes in part of URL and redirects the user to a file with that part of the URL as a query string.

Specifically, I'd like to redirect a user from the following:

```
http://localhost/SR/XXYYYZZ
```

to the following:

```
http://localhost/sr.php?sr=XXYYZZ
```

Here's how I've written the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SR/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^SR/(.*)$ sr.php?sr=$1 [L]
```

This clearly doesn't work.  My apologies if this is blatantly obvious.  I'm really a beginner when it comes to Apache and regular expressions.

Comment: +1 for clarity and indicating what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev/m/
RewriteRule ^sr/(.+)$ sr.php?sr=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Ansari.  It was definitely close.  Unfortunately, instead of redirecting to http://localhost/sr.php?sr=XXYYZZ it redirects to http://localhost/SR/sr.php?sr=XXYYZZ, leaving in the additional SR directory.  Now I need to figure out how to drop that additional SR directory.

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  It wasn't working.  I forgot that there was a RedirectMatch rule already set up in the VirtualHost.  If I turn this off, it doesn't work.  Maybe I should be more specific, the from URL is `http://localhost/dev/m/SR/XXYYZZ` and the to URL should be `http://localhost/dev/m/sr.php?sr=XXYYZZ`.  My error log says "File does not exist: /var/www/dev/m/SR."

Comment: Check now - and if it still doesn't work, can you mention where you're putting the .htaccess file? Also if it doesn't work, add an R flag to the L, NC, and QSA ones and see where the rewrite takes you.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I even added the R flag.  The .htaccess file is located in the same directory as my sr.php file which is localhost/var/www/dev/m/ directory.

Comment: Well, with the R flag, what does it rewrite to? Or doesn't it rewrite at all? In that case, is the file even being read at all? Can you add some junk characters in there and see if it throws a 500 error?

Comment: It doesn't rewrite to anything.  I guess the file is not even being read because I put some nonsense in there and there was no error.

Comment: In that case, check your virtualhost config and see if `AllowOverride All` is set or not. I assume you're made sure that the rewrite module is installed and enabled?

Comment: Haha glad to hear it works .. Good luck! (please mark this as the answer if it helped you)

Comment: Done!  I'd upvote you too, but I'm still new to StackOverflow and that requires 15 reputation.

Comment: No problem - thanks for accepting it, and I'd appreciate it if you upvoted it when you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/SR/ sr.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^SR/ sr.php [L]
```

then in `sr.php`

```
$sr = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4);
```

This avoids parameter escaping issues with mod_rewrite.